# jQuery: Difference between position() and offestParent()

Tags: jquery

What is the difference between position() and offestParent()? I tried to do the following in a click event:

```
console.info($(this).position(), $(this).offestParent());
```

Both are return same value. I have a confusion between offestParent() and position() function.

Comment: Have you tried looking them both up in http://api.jquery.com/ ?

Comment: What the hell!?? What do you mean with `same value`?? It's impossible that `offsetParent()` returns the same value than `position()`. The first returns an element and the second returns an object with values

Answer (score 1):

It actually depends upon where you are using the code.

1. The ***position()*** method allows us to retrieve the current position of an element relative to the offset parent.
2. The ***offsetParent()*** method returns the first positioned parent element.

Click on the below links for further information

1.[position()](https://api.jquery.com/position/)
2.[offsetParent()](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/css_offsetparent.asp)